# How can I make a REST controller conditional on the environment?

Tags: spring, rest, maven, spring-boot, spring-config

We have a use case where we want a set of endpoints to be enabled in every environment except the production environment.  Rather than implementing a custom security implementation for this use case, our idea was to use a variation of Spring's Conditional annotation to only enable the controller in non-production environments.

Our initial attempt was to use @ConditionalOnExpression by injecting a dynamic system property that specifies the type of environment (eg. dev, test, prod, etc.) and to match that property against a regular expression, but we have not been able to get the SpEL expressions to resolve properly in a way that suits our needs.

```java
@RestController
@ConditionalOnExpression("${property.name} matches ^((?!prod).)*$")
public class TestDataController
```

We have also considered using @ConditionalOnProperty, but there seems to be no way to allow this property to accept multiple valid values.

```java
@RestController
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "property.name",
        havingValue = "value1" or "value2",
        matchIfMissing = true)
public class TestDataController
```

Our last attempt was to write a custom class extending Spring's Conditional class to suit our needs.  This works for now, but it is relying on Java file I/O, which we would like to avoid if possible.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 29 May 19**

We were able to use the following solution to solve our problem:

1. Define a custom conditional in the following way:

```java
public class NotInProductionCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        final String env = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("property.name");
        if (env == null || env.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return !env.contains("prod");
    }
}
```

2. Use the custom condition on our controller:

```java
@RestController
@Conditional(NotInProductionCondition.class)
public class TestDataController
```

Comment: Use `Profile` annotation. It uses conditions internally

Comment: Thanks, @EbrahimPasbani.  This would work, but we chose a different approach. 
 See the update above for the approach that we took.

Comment: No problem. Yeah that approach is better and more clean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use @Profile annotation to instantiate a bean depending on a profile set in your environment.

```
@RestController
@Profile("!prod")
class MyController {
  ...
}
```

If you don't use profiles in your environment you most likely using some type of environment variable to specify the environment name, I suppose. You can make it a spring profile like this

```
spring.profiles.active = ${environmentName}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This would work, but we chose a different approach.  See the update to the question for the approach that we took.